# How to disable landscape on collectionView swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

My app supports both landscape and portrait but I want to disable landscape rotation on one of my collectionViews and viewControllers. My code below works on viewController but not in collectionView. Any suggestions?

```
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool{
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can add that to a component like CollectionView, its a property of the ViewController. Guess the solution is to handle the constrains of the collection view when screen rotates.

Comment: So there is no way that I can disable rotation in my UICollectionViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

I always use this

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

Also, there's no such thing as rotating `UICollectionView`, It's your `ViewController`

**Just like in a car, the driver handles the entire car**

Edit :

> It might be the right code, but not in the right ViewController. For
>   example, if the View Controller is embedded in a
>   UINavigationController, the navigation controller can still rotate,
>   causing the View Controller to still rotate. It really depends on your
>   specific situation.

Assuming your  `ViewController` is embedded into navigationController, Your best bet is subclassing UINavigationController

```
import UIKit    

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        if !viewControllers.isEmpty {
            // Check if this ViewController is the one you want to disable roration on
            if topViewController!.isKindOf(ViewController) {               //ViewController is the name of the topmost viewcontroller

                // If true return false to disable it
                return false
            }
        }
        // Else normal rotation enabled
        return true
       }
    }
```

If you want to disable autorotation throughout the navigation controller, remove the if condition and return false always

Comment: So is there a way to disable landscape in UICollectionViewController?

Comment: As mentioned, UICollectionViewController is a view controller that specializes in managing a collection view., so YES

Comment: I tried your code but my screen still rotates. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh yes. My controller is embedded to a nav controller.

Comment: wait, i am updating my answer

Comment: I put a break point in your custom class but there is no break while the code is running. Suggestion?